# prettyphoto not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't get it working anyone out there can help

I use this in the head

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I use this for photos

```
rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><
```

I use this before the closing body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            animationSpeed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
            padding: 40, /* padding for each side of the picture */
            opacity: 0.35, /* Value betwee 0 and 1 */
            showTitle: true, /* true/false */
            allowresize: true, /* true/false */
            counter_separator_label: '/', /* The separator for the gallery counter 1 "of" 2 */
            theme: 'light_rounded' /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square */
        });
    });
</script>
```

I linked the prettphoto CSS to my document
What do I do with the jquery.js and the jquery-1.3.2.min.js folders?

Comment: You might want to format the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up Tatu, you beat me to it. :)

Comment: What happens if you change rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" to rel="prettyPhoto"?

Comment: getting rid of the brackets did not work

Comment: Is anything happening at all?  Can you describe the error?

Comment: My photo changes from thumbnail to fullscreen but no prettyphoto effect

Comment: Link the actual page if you don't know how to check for errors yourself; it sounds like there is no event becoming attached to your link and it is just firing the link.

Comment: That's likely my problem I don't know how to apply  the jquery.js and the jquery-1.3.2.min.js folders to my html doc.

Comment: Anyone know how to link my html to the jquery.js and the jquery-1.3.2.min.js folders? Where do they go?

Comment: By adding the `<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` code in your html, jquery is linked. Best practice is to place them just before the </body> tag and before any javascript that uses the reference.

Comment: Also, and apologies if this seems just brutally obvious: jquery-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.prettyPhoto.js have to both be in a folder called "js" in the same directory as the HTML file you're working on.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure the js and css folders are positioned relative to your current page. For example, if you are working on http://localhost/photogallery/index.html, make sure the 3 folders included with your prettyPhoto download get extracted to http://localhost/photogallery/, and not the root of your server.
2. Make sure you have the prettyPhoto "images" folder. It includes a number of themes and other resources necessary for prettyPhoto to look right.
3. A conflicting library or version of jQuery may be stopping prettyPhoto from loading. Try running prettyPhoto on a blank page with just the necessary scripts and CSS included, and a couple image links with rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]". If this works, and when you bring the code back in to your page it doesn't work, you can know that something is conflicting on the page with prettyPhoto or jQuery.
4. Check for any errors on the page. Internet Explorer has the Developer Tools. Firefox has Firebug. Chrome has Developer tools. Search online for how to use the one particular to your favorite browser.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dawson said in his number 4 answer, check to make sure you don't have any javascript errors on your page that would be stopping prettyPhoto from loading correctly.

I was banging my head against my keyboard for 2 hours b/c it wasn't working for me. In Firefox, I used **Tools > Web Developer > Error Console** to see that I had a JavaScript code from another widget I'm using throwing an error. I commented out that line and it worked correctly.

Check check, and check again.